# Split an array with ; and deleted at the end ofstring if it exist to get an array

Tags: python, arrays, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

want to create a new column based on a string column that have as separator(";") and delete (";") in the end if exist using python/pyspark :

Inputs :

```
"511;520;611;"
"322;620"  
"3;321;"
"334;344"
```

expected Output :

```
+Column        | +new column
"511;520;611;" | [511,520,611]
"322;620"      | [322,620]
"3;321;"       | [3,321]
"334;344"      | [334,344]
```

try :

```
data = data.withColumn(
"newcolumn",
split(col("column"), ";"))
```

but i get an empty string at the end of the array like here and i want to delete it if exist

```
+Column        | +new column
"511;520;611;" | [511,520,611,empty string]
"322;620"      | [322,620]
"3;321;"       | [3,321,empty string]
"334;344"      | [334;344]
```

Comment: `split(col("column").strip(";"), ";")` should do the trick

Comment: strip is a python function applied on strings and we cannot use it on a col("column") in pyspark

Comment: oh really? I didn't know its type wasn't `str`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for spark version >= 2.4, use `filter` function with `!= ''` condition to filter out empty strings in an array

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

data = data.withColumn("newcolumn", expr("filter(split(column, ';'), x -> x != '')"))
```